# Wordpress Multisite - Mature Option - What does it do?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have some multisites and I am wondering what the "Mature" options does with the site. I have a small code that uses this function to sort the sites in categories, and I was wondering if this may hurt my SEO. The site does not contain any mature material.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score -1):

According to your question, I found some useful blog from Wordpress [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/mature-content/).

In this article, it does state that:

`A website that is marked as Mature is excluded from public areas of the WordPress.com service. This means:`

`It will not appear in the Reader or other tag listings
It will not appear in Top Blogs listings, recent posts, or related posts listings on other blogs
The associated users cannot use that URL as a link in their WordPress.com Forums profile`

So for the SEO sight of view, I think it was slightly hurting your SEO performance (for my point of view).

However, we can always create redirecting pages and link from other page to it. So I think that was not a big problem :D

Hope it helps!

Comment: Allright thanks! But this is only Wordpress.com right? How about a self hosted wordpress.org site?

Comment: Hi @Fredrik since self Wordpress.org site is not hosted by Wordpress.com so I think that the above situation doesn't applied. SEO still rocks :D

Comment: Great! I wonder why the function even exist in self hosted sites then?